# Configure R --enable-BLAS-shlib with MKL

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu, intel-mkl

I'm trying to compile R 3.3.1 on Ubuntu Server 16.04. I've successfully compiled this version of R previously on the same computer, but now I can't get R to compile.

My goal is to use the [HiPLARM package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/HiPLARM/index.html). I've been following the installation instructions for HiPLARM, so I needed to recompile R with **shared BLAS** (I'm using MKL). I uninstalled my previous installation, and I've added the additional `--enable-BLAS-shlib` flag to `configure`, but the compilation fails. When I remove the additional flag (and return to my original configuration settings), the compilation appears to work, but installation fails. I don't know what would have changed on my system that would have allowed me to successfully compile the same version of R with the same installation instructions but not doesn't.

Here are the specifics. I run this script:

```
export MKLPATH=/opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64_lin
export MKLINCLUDE=/opt/intel/mkl/include

export R_PAPERSIZE=letter
export R_BATCHSAVE=--no-save

export FFLAGS="-I$MKLINCLUDE"
export CFLAGS="-march=native -O3 -m64 -I$MKLINCLUDE"
export CXXFLAGS="-march=native -O3 -m64 -I$MKLINCLUDE"
export FCFLAGS="-I$MKLINCLUDE"
MKL="-L$MKLPATH -Wl,--no-as-needed -lmkl_gf_lp64 -lmkl_gnu_thread -lmkl_core -lgomp -lpthread -lm -ldl"

./configure --with-blas="$MKL" --with-lapack
```

The configure summary appears as expected, so I then use `make` to compile, and everything appears fine except:

```
main.c: In function ‘dummy_ii’:
main.c:1656:12: warning: function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]
    return (uintptr_t) &ii;
```

When I run R from the `bin` directory, everything appears to be working correctly. I can multiply two 5000x5000 matrices of random normal draws in less time than without MKL. However, when I use `make install` or `checkinstall`, I receive the following errors:

```
installing doc ...
/usr/bin/install: cannot stat 'NEWS': No such file or directory
/usr/bin/install: cannot stat 'NEWS.pdf': No such file or directory
/usr/bin/install: cannot stat 'NEWS.rds': No such file or directory
/usr/bin/install: cannot stat 'NEWS': No such file or directory
/usr/bin/install: cannot stat 'NEWS.pdf': No such file or directory
Makefile:119: recipe for target 'install-sources2' failed
make[1]: *** [install-sources2] Error 1
```

Also, when I attempt to use the `--enable-BLAS-shlib` flag in my script, I receive many warnings of `implicit declaration of function`, and the compiling eventually fails with many `undefined reference` errors. I've found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32807525/build-r-from-source-links-to-shared-libraries-failed), but the script isn't successful for me (perhaps because I'm not using the Intel compilers?).

Any help would be tremendously appreciated!

Comment: It's a FAQ and we've been over this a number of times. See eg [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29986242/143305). Closing this...

Comment: Hi Dirk, thank you for the link. It is helpful. However, the link doesn't address the first part of my question, namely the error I get and why I can't use `make install` to complete the installation. Do you have any ideas about these?

Comment: It is my sincere belief that you are better off not compiling locally.  The pre-built packages are correctly configured, reliable, and frequently updated.  You can switch BLAS/LAPACK libraries with them at will.  And in the narrow sense the failure looks look an upstream bug related to building in a clean directory which I reported recently and which has been fixed.  Disable the `NEWS.rds` target in `doc/Makefile` if you must...